# why variable in function protect( ) output nothing?

Tags: php, mysqli

I wrote this code to read the access leve of users logged in so, protect access to pages based on the access level of user logged in

and do function has `sessionloginid` and `$v` but `$v` variable output nothing
what I need to edit in the function code?
**error message appear say :**
**Notice: Undefined variable: v**

```
 if(isset($_SESSION['sessionloginid']))// point to id of user logged in
        {  
        $query =
        "SELECT * 
        FROM privilege 
        where login_id='".$_SESSION['sessionloginid']."'  " ;



    $access_level= array();
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$query) or die('');
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
            {


         $_SESSION['sessionloginid']= $row['login_id']; 
        $_SESSION['sessionaccess']= $row['AccessLevel'];//output 
         $access_level[]=$_SESSION['sessionaccess'];
        print_r ($access_level);//Array([0]=>1)Array([0]=>1[1]=>2) 

        }   }

foreach($access_level as $k => $v)
    {
        print_r($v) ;// output 12 

    }
function protect(){
 if($_SESSION['sessionloginid']==true && $v !=1)
 {
 echo $v; //output nothing
 }

}
    protect($v);
```

Comment: Where is `$v` coming from? Nowhere! That's why it outputs nothing. If you had error reporting set to report noticves you would have seen this.

Comment: Nicely-indented code would probably also make the problem more obvious.

Comment: thank you  Glavić I use global variable and error meassage disappear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass in `$v` as a function parameter

```
protect($v);
```

At it's current scope, once the foreach loop ends, $v doesn't exist. It only exists within the loop, so you'll have to either call the function inside the loop, or set a variable on a higher scope to the value so you can use it elsewhere.

Comment: I edit the code to match your answer but error message appear say Notice: Undefined variable: v

Comment: I'm assuming you didn't set a variable to $v at all. Read what I said again

Comment: thank you I use global variable and error meassage disappear

Comment: Good man! Happy coding